# mySQL complex SELECT query?

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my table structure:

```
users:

id | email

emails:

id | subject | body

user_emails:

user_id | email_id
```

It's very simple design. However, I need to select the first (lowest) emails.id for all users.id's that are not associated in user_emails.

To illustrate:

```
users:

id | email
1 | email@domain.com
2 | test@lol.com
3 | user@test.com

emails:

id | subject | body
1 | sub1 | body1
2 | sub2 | body2

user_emails:

user_id | email_id
1 | 1
1 | 2
2 | 1
```

As the data shows:

- User 1 received email 1 and 2 already so the select should exclude
  that user.
- User 2 only received email 1, so it should select user 2
  and email 2.
- User 3 didn't receive any emails, so it should select user 3
  and email 1.

I'll be doing this in PHP so any logic should be in written in PHP if it can't be done with mySQL alone.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** I should probably mention that there will be thousands of user ID's and hundreds of email id's. The script that will send out all these emails will run once daily. So, this should be as optimized as possible.

Comment: I have but I'm not very experienced with mySQL and it get confusing for me.

Comment: Your answer should be posted a such, and then you should accept an answer. :-)

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer, instead of marking your question [SOLVED]. Your answer (which you can accept as correct after a short delay) will help other people in the future who find this question in a search. (The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) explains how answering your own question helps.) Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought of a much simpler solution to all this. I added a lastSent column to the users table.

```
// Load all emails into an array. Use the id as the key.
$sql = "SELECT * FROM emails";
$query = mysql_query( $sql );
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $query ) ) {
    $emails[ $row['id'] ] = $row;
}

// Load all users into an array.
$sql = "SELECT id, email, lastSent FROM users";
$query = mysql_query( $sql );
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $query ) ) {
    $users = $row;
}

// Loop through each user and send next email from the list based on lastSent value.
foreach ( $users as $user ) {
    $id = $user['lastSent'] + 1;
    $email = $user['email'];
    $subject = $emails[$id]['subject'];
    $body = $emails[$id]['body'];
    $send = mail($email, $subject, $body);
    if ( $send ) {
            // Update lastSent value.
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET lastSent='$id' WHERE id='" . $user['id'] . "'";
        mysql_query( $sql );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Could try the below:

```
SELECT * from users u 
LEFT JOIN users_emails e ON u.id=e.user_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN emails m on m.id=1 
WHERE e.user_id is NULL
```

Or use the below if the id in emails not necessary to be 1 as above query.

```
SELECT * from users u 
LEFT JOIN users_emails e ON u.id=e.user_id 
LEFT OUTER join emails m on m.id=(SELECT id from emails order by id limit 1)   
WHERE e.user_id is NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a try with the below query

select t.id, min(t.q_id) from (SELECT u.id, e.id as q_id FROM users u CROSS JOIN emails e) as t  where (t.id, t.q_id) not in (select * from user_emails) group by t.id